# contextmanager python just for calling function

Tags: python, contextmanager

I don't understand what is the different between:

```
@contextmanager
def function_decorator(msg, logger):
    # wrap function
    logger.info('START: -- {} --'.format(msg))

    yield

    logger.info('END: -- {} --'.format(msg))

with function_decorator(msg='my funcion call', logger):
    my_function()
```

and:

```
msg='my funcion call'
logger.info('START: -- {} --'.format(msg))
my_function()
logger.info('END: -- {} --'.format(msg))
```

Is there any different beside beauty  ?

Comment: That context manager seems very unnecessary. I ussually only use them to handle cleanup code nicer.

Comment: @RoadRunner this is not the case for me I think it will be useful I am just afraid I will get unexpected results. Can you answer the post Q ?

Comment: Aside a tad too generic function name, it's not that much about just beauty but reducing clutter. Imagine normal production code full of statements like that to log duration, I'd much rather use that two-line version with context manager than add all those print statements every. single. time.

Speaking of decorators, I'd probably use decorator like `@log_start_stop` or similar. so that I would not need to instrument calling code.